# php taking a text file and separating it into arrays with provinces and cities

Tags: php, regex

I have a file of provinces and cities in order but I have to get a way to separate them and later compare. Having trouble getting them separated in a manageable way.

format is:

```
province~city
province~city
```

etc

so far I am not sure so I am trying

```
$dataFromFile = file('provine_city.txt');
$dataFromFile = array_map('trim', $dataFromFile);
$result = array();
foreach ($dataFromFile as $line) {
  list($province, $city) = explode('~', $line);
  $arrayPfCities = explode
}
```

Comment: And what error or unwanted behaviour or output are you getting?

Comment: Use [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) with a delimiter of `~`

Comment: Everything is fine, right up to `$arrayPfCities = explode` where it seems like you've just gone "ah... fukkit" and posted here...

Answer (score 2):

Two changes:

1. As mentioned in the comments, use `fgetcsv()` to parse the file data
2. Put everything into an array using the province as a key. That way your cities are all grouped by province for easy retrieval.

I define some constants to make the array keys more human readable. You don't have to do that.

Sample code:

```
define('PROVINCE', 0);
define('CITY', 1);
$results = array();
if (($handle = fopen("provine_city.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "~")) !== FALSE) {
        $results[$data[PROVINCE]][] = $data[CITY];
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: It would seem as though you'd be overwriting the value of `$results[$data[PROVINCE]]` anytime there is more than 1 city for a given province. Maybe it should be `$results[$data[PROVINCE]][] = $data[CITY]` instead?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Ahh. Typo on my part. Good catch.

Comment: I do what I can for a fellow New Jerseyan.